# Node.js race condition sending data to ejs file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to get lab data from a my mongodb server. I am able to get the data as I can console log it however I feel like Im coming across a race condition where the res.render happens before the actual db call. Now I tried nesting the calls so that the render happens after I get the data as follows:

```
    Lab.find()
        .then( (result)=>{
            console.log(result)
            res.render('main/labs', { results : result});
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).render('main/error')
        })
});
```

However I always end up with the same error so I'm not sure if I am nesting the function calls properly or I am over looking something else.

```
  {
    _id: 607fc39492b8a4ada9aec28a,
    title: 'Lab 01',
    description: 'Highlight Table Cells',
    filename: '01_lab'
  }
]
[2021-04-21T02:51:34.962] [INFO] default FROM=> http://localhost:3000/home,  TO=> GET /labs, STATUS=> 500 
TypeError: /home/christien/Desktop/web-development/JavaScript_Demos/Labs/resources/main/labs.ejs:15
    13|             <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
    14|                 <div class="card-body">
 >> 15|                     <h5 class="card-title"><%= results[i].title %></h5>
    16|                     <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    17|                     <p class="card-text"><%=results[i]%></p>
    18|                     <a href="#" class="card-link">Go To Lab</a>
```

Please help!

**EDIT:**

here is the ejs file that I am trying to load

```
        <h3>Labs</h3>
        <p>The following are labs that have been completed</p>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-sm-between align-items-center">
            <% for (var i =0; i <= results.length; i++ ) { %>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><%= results[i].title %></h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Description</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Go To Lab</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to following

```
Lab.find().exec().then((results) => {
  // handle results 
})
```